# How can I pass user credentials to a custom tableau portal? I've seen it done on youtube

Tags: customization, tableau-api

I'm currently trying to build a custom tableau portal but was wondering how I would have to pass it credentials for the user to login to server. I have read the JS api documentation but dont see much about security credentials for users.

Comment: What kind of security credentials? For the data source, or to log on to Tableau Server?

Comment: Also, if you could post the relevant video, then that would be helpful. :)